# Newsletter HTML : fonts and vertical align

Tags: css, html-table, outlook, html-email, newsletter

I'm creating an HTML newsletter. I'm using nested array. I have two question : how do I import font? Because **@import** and **@font-face** are not working on my newsletter (but works on simple html)

And the second is this :

How can I " *vertical align middle* " 2 span with different font-size ? It's working on simple html but not on the newsletter...

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:10px;">
        <div>                      
            <!--[if mso]>
                                          <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://" style="height:60px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:180px;" arcsize="17%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#00436f">
                                            <w:anchorlock/>
                                            <center>
                                          <![endif]-->
                          <a href="#"
                                            style="background-color:#00436f;font-weight:bold;border-radius:10px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:180px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;padding-top: 25px; padding-bottom: 25px;">                                                                                                            <span style="font-size:2em;font-weight:bold;vertical-align:middle">15</span>&nbsp;
                                          <span style="font-size:1.2em;font-weight:bold;text-transform:uppercase;vertical-align:middle">Février</span>
                                            </a>
                              <!--[if mso]>
                                        </center>
                                      </v:roundrect>
                                    <![endif]-->
              </div>
        <!--<p style="Margin: 0;font-size: 14px;line-height: 17px;width: 100%;padding: 25px 0;text-align: center;border-radius: 10px;background: #00436f;-->
        <!--      color: white;">-->
        <!--</p>-->
        <p style="padding-top:10px;Margin: 0;line-height:1;font-size: 1em;font-weight:bold;color:#797979">Réunion d'information Loiret Numérique</p>
        <p style="Margin: 0;font-size: 12px;line-height: 14px">
          Mairie de Montargis - Salle Montdignan
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What I get:

[image]

What I need:

[image]

My fonts :

```
@media screen{
@import url("https://use.typekit.net/jqe0zpu.css");
@import url("https://www.site.fr/.../GT-Walsheim-Regular.ttf");

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Walsheim';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  src: local("Walsheim"),url('https://www.site.fr/.../GT-Walsheim-Regular.eot');

}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Walsheim';
  src: local("Walsheim"),url('https://www.site.fr/.../GT-Walsheim-Bold.eot');
  src: url('https://www.site.fr/.../GT-Walsheim-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('https://www.site.fr/.../GT-Walsheim-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
    url('https://www.site.fr/.../GT-Walsheim-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('https://www.site.fr/.../GT-Walsheim-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
  font-weight: 800;
  font-style: normal;
}       
    }
```

Comment: How do you mean `@font-face` doesn't work? As I Know, newsletter design is same as design for "normal" page

Comment: This is a good guide as to what css you can and can't use in emails - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ and this shows font face support https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/text-fonts/font-face/

Comment: Many mail clients are very limited what they can do with html/css. Which versions of outlook you want to support, and do you want to support other mail clients too? If so which ones?

Comment: My fonts are ignored by the client (my main client is Outlook 2010). @Pete I've seen this, and I change some of my code based on this. But my problem is still here

Comment: Post your code in regards to style sheets and how you are importing fonts. Just remember that Outlook and Gmail do not work with web-based fonts like Google fonts. Outlook will default to `Times New Roman` Since you're showing a serif font as output, I think that is the issue.

Comment: See my updated post

Comment: Go with Gwally's code. Emails have very patchy support for web fonts and for vertical alignment just use a table with two columns. That should solve that part.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, Outlook does not work with all web-fonts like Google fonts. You don't include full paths to resources so there is no way for us to test what you are doing and look for a solution.

My first suggestion is to open your email in a web browser and test to see if it works at all. If it does, then I suggest testing what you are doing in an Apple or IOS email client, since they seem to work well with web fonts. If it works, you know you have things coded correctly.

Generally an HTML document wih a web font needs a link to that font and applied in a class for use in the document.

You should have a link like this:

```
<style>
  @import url("https://www.site.fr/.../GT-Walsheim-Regular.ttf");
</style>
```

Or this:

```
<link href="https://use.typekit.net/jqe0zpu.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Next, you need to find some way to get the font out into the document.

```
<style>
.classname { 
  font-family: GT-Walsheim, Arial, sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

In the last example, I added Arial as a fallback font that is pretty web-safe because Walsheim is not going to work with Gmail and most likely not work with Outlook 2007, 2010, 2013-2019.

Finally, apply the classname:

```
<p class="classname">Hello</p>
```

You could go fancy and add in inline styles as well:

```
<p class="classname" style="font-family: GT-Walsheim, Arial, sans-serif;">Hello</p>
```

This is a very basic plan on how to work with web fonts in email.

Good luck.

Comment: Why does the fonts not going to work ? I need my font to be this one...

Comment: @ProjetSin The fonts do not work because Gmail and Outlook do not support web fonts. I know it sounds ridiculous, but Gmail does not support Google fonts in Gmail. That's why I encourage you to choose a web safe font like Arial as a backup.

Comment: Ok thanks. If it doesn't support Webfont, why does it looks like anyone achieve this but me :') ? Because answers below seems to work for other

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler method of using `div` tags:

```html
<style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
  #fevrier {
    background: #00436f;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 180px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    vertical-align: middle -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
  }
  
  #fevrier .text {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
</style>


<div id="fevrier">
  15 <span class="text">FÉVRIER </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not what I want, your code show the date with the same font size, I need 2 verticaly align different font size (as my images show)

Comment: replace css with 16px and 12px respectively

Comment: If you are going to answer the question, you must post your markup here, not a third party site.

Comment: sorry my code is pasted above, you can check or edit it and run on codepen .. its just a matter of changing "font-size:1em;" to "font-size;12px;" and "font-size:1.2em;" to "font-size;16px;" .. The thridparty "codepen" allows you to test.. the code. So kindly find the code above, and the changes required is in this comment.

Comment: you can place the <div id="fevrier">15  <span class = "text">FÉVRIER <span>
</div> inside the table.. it will render the same. Thanks